# Visual Studio 2010 C++ IDE - Auto-implement parent class pure virtual members

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, ide

Is there any way for Visual Studio IDE to automatically create (autocomplete) the bare codebase for a new class' parent class' virtual methods (ie. all parent members are `virtual rval foo(x) = 0;`) without using a class wizard?

Comment: VisualAssist will do this. I doubt bare vs2010 will.

Comment: Are there any other IDE's that have this feature that are free which can utilize the MS C++ compiler and linker tools?